# windows server 2008 r2 how to limit access to smb by ip range?

Tags: windows-server-2008, file-sharing, subnet, server-message-block

Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. Only role installed is File Server -> File Server Resource Manager.  Box is member of AD.  I have local admin access and can put in a ticket with domain admin if need be.

I created an SMB share and granted permissions to a domain group.  This takes care of account management.  However, I would like to limit access to the share to certain subnets.  Is there a way to limit the access to an SMB share by IP address range/subnet?  If access to individual shares cannot be configured by IP range then what about access to SMB as a whole no matter which share?

Thanks in advance for any insights you may be able to provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Windows Firewall with Advanced Security to modify the scope of the File and Printer Sharing (SMB-in) rule for the appropriate network profile to allow inbound SMB connections from the appropriate subnets.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, that worked!  Will come back and vote up once I get enough rep to do so.

Comment: Glad to help...